# WP Rest API and json_decode()

Tags: plugins, json, rest-api

I'm getting familiar with the WP REST API 2 plugin and I started following the amazing directions from [Torque's Guide](http://hs.wpengine.com/torque-wordpress-rest-api-ebook-torque).

Everything seems pretty clear but I'm having trouble understanding this error (Keep in mind I've follow and reviewed all directions step by step. Here is the function I'm using:

```
$url = 'http://rbm.dev/wp-json/wp/v2/works/53';

$response = wp_remote_get( $url );

function slug_get_json( $url ) {
    //GET the remote site
    $response = wp_remote_get( $url );
    //Check for error
    if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
        return sprintf( 'The URL %1s could not be retrieved.', $url ); //get just the body
        $data = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );
    }
    //return if not an error
    if ( ! is_wp_error( $response ) ) { //decode and return
        return json_decode( $response );
    }
}
```

I can easely see the JSON object if accesed through a restful client such as PAW or directly from the browser. But the function is returning this:

```
Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given...
```

I'm understanding the logic of the function but since I'm so new to this I'm not certain about the error. Not sure why json_decode() is not receiving the data as it's supposed to do. Keep in mind this is exactly from the Torque's book -- is there a mistake in the syntax of the function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wp_remote_get` return array of results containing keys `body`, `headers`, `response` etc depending on arguments.

And `json_decode` only accept JSON string. So correct your code in this way

```
//return if not an error
    if ( ! is_wp_error( $response ) ) { //decode and return
        return json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ) );
    }
```

Ref: [Return Values of `wp_remote_get` or `wp_remote_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_post#Return_Values)

Comment: Thank you! this makes sense -- Do you think that is an error in the publication?
From the author referring to that snippet:
_Although you can get the body directly using wp_remote_retrieve_body(), this is a bad idea because, if something was wrong with your request or the server making the request, it could be a WP_Error instead of the actual response you need._

Comment: @mmarquez I am not sure about the book, we follow codex because we can see it and we can edit it. We are already checking `! is_wp_error( $response )` so it will not go inside the `if` block if something goes wrong in WordPress and `wp_remote_retrieve_body` also check for the same. On other hand for server errors you can check header status code to handle `400`, `500` errors!